# How to send hostname and/or ip address into own container using environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm currently using docker in swarm mode and I want to send the container's hostname and/or ip address into said container using environment variables.

```
version: "3"
services:
  test:
    image: someimage
    deploy: 
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    environment:
      - HOSTNAME=test
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    external:
      name: my-network
```

I tried using the example above but it does not work. The goal was to each replica to have its own hostname and/or ip address. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each container has a hostname that is the same as it's short ID, which is already set as variable HOSTNAME in the container.

If you're trying to access replicas directly from other containers on that docker network, you can use reverse lookups (nslookup, dig) tasks. to get the list of IP's (which you shouldn't hardcode in config or compose files)

If you want to inject the hostname of the host into the service tasks, you can use [templates in compose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates).

Comment: Hey you seem quite knowledgeable, I have a situation where I have 5 replicas that 
need to be able to communicate with eachother. Eventually each of these replicas will be on an overlay network but for now theyre on the default bridge network. How would I go about 'knowning' the ips assigned by docker in order to communicate with these other replicas ? I thought about static ips but idk if that's the right way..

Comment: Please ask a new question Eladian